# Error while executing a linux command through java - The operator > is undefined for the argument types java.lang.String

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to run a shell command through my Java API but i get an error - "The operator > is undefined for the argument types java.lang.String"

```
 Process pdb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("$commandString . " 2> " . $stderr_file . " > " . $stdout_file, $output, $rcode");
```

I am not sure if there is something missing from the above statement. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes that are part of the command

Answer (score 1):

```
.exec("$commandString . " 2> " . $stderr_file . " > " . $stdout_file, $output, $rcode");
       ^--start/end-----^                                         what's this for? --^
          java string
```

So now you finish your java string, and go into `2>`, which makes no logical sense to java. Perhaps you mean something more like

```
.exec("$commandString" . " 2> " . $stderr_file . " > " . $stdout_file, $output, $rcode");
                     ^---
```

but note that even this doesn't make sense. For building strings, you use `+`, not `.`. This is Java, not PHP.

Comment: `$name` is also just that string literal and will not get replaced by the content of a variable called `name`.
Also `>2` is a shell specific option, i.e. it tells a shell to divert the stderr of the command, it has no meaning as part of an `exec` command. Same for `>`. These strings will be passed the the command like any of the other arguments.